# PHP fopen with proxy and https

Tags: php, ssl, proxy, openssl, fopen

I'm using `fopen` of PHP to connect to other sites, but it doesn't work. The requesting server use a proxy and the target server is on https. So here are the context configuration :

```
["http"]=> array(5) { 
   ["method"]=> string(3) "GET" 
   ["ignore_errors"]=> int(1) 
   ["header"]=> string(197) "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Authorization: Basic ...." 
   ["proxy"]=> string(23)     "tcp://192.168.83.6:8080" 
   ["request_fulluri"]=> bool(true) 
}
```

Gives a response : `Bad Request. Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.`

So I searched a bit and following some guides, this is my new configuration using ssl proxy protocol:

```
["http"]=> array(5) { 
   ["method"]=> string(3) "GET" 
   ["ignore_errors"]=> int(1) 
   ["header"]=> string(197) "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded Authorization: Basic ...." 
   ["proxy"]=> string(23)     "ssl://192.168.83.6:8080" 
   ["request_fulluri"]=> bool(true) 
},

 //http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php
'ssl' => array(
     'verify_peer' => true,
     'allow_self_signed' => true,
     'cafile'        => '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt',
     'verify_depth'  => 5,
     'CN_match' => 'somesite.com',
     'disable_compression' => true,
     'SNI_enabled'         => true,
   )
```

Error : `Warning: fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:func(119):reason(252) in ...php on line 237 Warning: fopen(): Failed to enable crypto in ...`

OpenSSL support enabled

OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010

Please help!